# Breaker setup for Trane 4 ton heat pump variable speed air handler without heat strips

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel

I have a Trane heat pump 4 ton xr-16 and associated heat pump.  The air handler is wired to a double pole (240v) 60 Amp breaker.   Since I do not intend to install heat strips (ever - I have a better alternative heat source), does the air handler (variable speed) that draws only 6.81 amps when running require 240v or 60Amp breakers?

Comment: What does the installation manual say? Is the same circuit powering the heat pump (outside unit) or is that on a separate breaker?

Comment: Heat pump (outside unit) on separate 220 - 40 Amp breakers as called for in the manual and on the unit itself.

Comment: Voltages in the U.S. are 120/240. Are you somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post the actual model number of your air handler? Do you have both the indoor and outdoor units on the same circuit, or are they on separate circuits/breakers?

Comment: TEM6A0  variable speed (C42H41S, C48H41S or D48H41S - not sure, would have to go in attic and look.  The air handler and the compressor are on separate 220 breakers in separate panels.  The installers used the old 220/60A breakers for the air handler (in which they did install heat strips, which I am removing) and then ran new wiring to the compressor from a sub panel on 220 / 60 amp breakers (which I have reduced to 40A to match mfg recommendations after my original compressor burned out).

Comment: it is a TEM6A0C48H41SB, 220V - with 15 W breaker heat strip (which I do not ever want to use).  the 15W breaker heat strip calls for 32A, there is no specification for amps on AHC, but it does call for 220.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need to switch that breaker for a 2 pole 15A breaker *anyway*

The [submittal (on p. 7)](https://resource.bakerdist.com/is/content/Watscocom/Gemaire/american-standard_tem6a0c48h41sb_article_11118874565477449_en_subs.pdf#page=7) for your air handler specifies a Maximum Overcurrent Protection of 15A for your case where no heat strips are fitted; as a result, you'll need to have the 2 pole 60A breaker changed out for a 2 pole 15A breaker to properly protect the air handler to begin with.  (This may or may not get you spaces, though, depending on your panel's ability to be double-stuffed.  We'll need to see photos of your panel in order to make a determination on that.)

Comment: Good research on page 7.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a breaker sized for the heat pump itself if there is not a secondary breaker. A 4 ton system will be at least 30 possibly 40 amps depending on its efficiency and how the system is wired.